# Slow down while loop to animate images sequence in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a simple game using html css javascript, the problem when I use while loop to animate a sequence of images when I press a key, it shows only the last one I know while loop works with processor speed but I need to animate images slowly without using css animation "@keyframes". thanks

```
var n=0;

function rotRight()
{
    var str1 = "url(sprt/trk";
    var str2 = ".png)";
    var ss=str1.concat(n);
    
    trk.style.backgroundImage=ss.concat(str2);

    while(n!=4)
    {
        if(n>4)
        {
            n--;    
        }
        else
        {
            n++;
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a JavaScript-based animation in the browser, you don't use a loop at all. Instead, you update the item, let the browser display that, then update it again after a delay, using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and/or [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). So you might do:

```
let n = 0;

rotRight();

function rotRight()
{
    // Do an update
    trk.style.backgroundImage = `url(sprt/trk${n}.png)`;

    // Schedule the next if appropraite
    if (n !== 4) {
        if (n > 4) {
            n--;    
        } else {
            n++;
        }
        setTimeout(rotRight, 1000); // 1000ms = one second
    }
}
```

(I've also updated the code to use `let` and `const` rather than `var` — `var` has no place in modern JavaScript — and to use a template literal to build the URLs.)

**But**, for many animations it may be important that each update calculates where it should be in the overall animation based on *time*, not iterations, because various things could prevent your code being run in a timely manner. In those cases, you remember when you started, then when you're called you figure out where you should be and update accordingly. Your background swapper may not need that, but more advanced ones would.